# Display web browser settings

Tags: browser

Working with different web-browsers with their string of version numbers along with their myriad list of configuration is a real pain.

I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a web-page that can dump the browser settings to the browser so that it can be saved and forwarded to the developer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

http://mybrowserinfo.com/detail.asp

Comment: Yes! Brilliant! I failed to find one after googling for 20mins. Thanks!

Comment: Umm ... spoke too soon. One of the pieces of information that I was after is the proxy settings. That did not show up.