# Can I detect certain browser (IE) setting (not change, detect)?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, trusted-sites, internet-options

I was just looking at this stackoverflow question: [Display web browser settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066686/display-web-browser-settings)

And that helps.

But, I'm curious if I can detect certain IE specific settings.  I'm thinking some of the stuff in the Advanced Tab (e.g. Is 'Enable Integrated Windows Authentication' on)?

Or that our site was added as a Trusted Site?  And within the Trusted Site settings, "Atomatic logon with current user name and password" is set?

I don't want to change them (I get that would be a huge issue that could be exploited).  I just want to be able to present to the User:

"Hey, you need these couple of settings checked or unchecked for the site to work properly.  Do this: a, b, c ... or Contact your Administrator".

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this from within a web site.

Comment: viewed 14 times in 5 days.  Half probably by me.  I guess I used a terrible title and/or tags - or people just don't care?  Anyhow, @Pekka - if you answer (instead of add a comment), I'll give you the green check-mark.

Comment: heh. I guess it's indeed because of the tags. Adding `html` to the mix would probably help but it wouldn't *really* fit... I could see `javascript` being somewhat legitimate, though. I'll add my comment as an answer. No need to accept it right away, you can look for some more popular tags. Not that I think there will be a different answer.

Comment: I changed the tags to your suggestions.  I'm not sure if it will help now that this is 6 days later ... but unless I hear something otherwise, you'll get the green check-mark for being first anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can query these settings from within a web site. Being able to do so might introduce security holes.

I'm sure some settings can be determined by using circumstantial evidence (like if a JavaScript doesn't execute, scripting is probably disabled). But I don't think there is a proper API to poll every setting; I guess the best you can do is serve the user some advice on what to look for. (like, "The xyz symbol in the bottom right bar should show a green checkmark like so.... the abc checkbox in the options dialog should be unchecked... etc")

Answer (score 1):

You can't check the settings directly, but you could test the functionality instead.  If you attempt to authenticate with the server and find out you don't have their credentials passed in properly, you know it's not configured right.  At this point you could show them your information about how to connect to the site.  This would be a better solution anyways, as you're better off testing for features rather than specific settings.

Comment: Thanks for the response - much appreciated.  You have given some good advice.

Answer (score 1):

To distill your question down, it looks like you're trying to find out whether IE is configured to automatically send NTLM credentials to your server.

Unfortunately, there's no way to cleanly feature-detect this.  My initial thought was to put a JavaScript file in a protected directory that simply set a global variable, and link to that script in the `<head>`.  (`<script src="protected-dir/test.js"></script>` – `protected-dir` would be configured only for integrated auth with anonymous auth off.)  If the script loads, the variable is set; and if it fails, the variable obviously isn't.  Another script on the page could check the variable and show a message if it's not set.

This works flawlessly when everything is configured correctly on a client, but when auto login is off, this causes an [ugly 401 dialog](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--oXfOvNi_fc/TZ8lHrpnDyI/AAAAAAAAADA/hh5fZB_dwwk/s1600/IEPrompt.jpg) to pop up, which is clearly no good.  Additionally, a XHR request isn't the answer since the spec [specifically says the browser *should* ask for credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29680/201952) if it gets a 401.

Sadly, I don't think there's a way to automatically determine if auto login is enabled without causing the 401 dialog to pop up.

Comment: Thanks for the response - you've really added a lot to this discussion.  Thanks again.